# How to configure zsh to clear history on exit?

Tags: zsh, iterm2

This used to be the default behavior on iTerm2 before I upgraded to macOS Calalina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not configured in iTerm2, but is set by macOS in Zsh itself. Since macOS Catalina, the file `/etc/zshrc` contains the following:

```bsh
HISTFILE=${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zsh_history
HISTSIZE=2000
SAVEHIST=1000
```

This causes the last 1K lines of history to be saved on exit.

To override this, add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
unset HISTFILE SAVEHIST
```

Documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-SAVEHIST

Comment: If `~/.zshrc` loads when the terminal loads, the problem I see here is that the OP would like to detect unload, so history is clear and secured after each exit. 

Otherwise, accessing or even transferring the history remotely without running ZSH. 

//  Will display the history without any work arounds or hacks
`> cat ~/.zsh_history`
// Will send your hist to a mounted thumb drive
`rsync -av ~/.zsh_history /media/xieerqi/A669-34EF/.jeff_bezos_zsh_history`.
 
The security ramification is that when this is set, initially all input will still be captured until the environment is reloaded.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1.**

`%> echo "\n# Clear ZSH history after each exit.\ntrap 'unset HISTFILE; rm ~/.zsh_history;HISTSIZE=0;'" >> .zshrc`

Now reload your ZSH terminal and you will never have history saved again unless you remove the above line from your .zshrc :).

You're done!